# code shows error when reading size of a variable

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Details from './Details';
import './index.css';

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      usersData: [],
      error: null,
      selectedUser: null,
    };
  }

  handleClick = (id) => {
    const selectedUser = this.state.usersData.find(user => user.id === id)
    this.setState(() => ({ selectedUser }))
  }
  findAlbum = (selectedUser, id) => {
    fetch(`https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/${id}/albums`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        selectedUser.albums = data;
      })
      .catch(err => this.setState({ error: err.message }))
  }


  setAlbum = (id) => {
    const selectedUser = this.state.usersData.find(user => user.id === id)
    this.findAlbum(selectedUser, id);
  }

  render() {
    this.state.usersData.forEach(user => {
      this.setAlbum(user.id)
    })

    const usersList = this.state.usersData.map(user => {
      return <li key={user.id} onClick={() => this.handleClick(user.id)}>{user.name} {user.username} {user.email} {user.albums.size}</li>
    })

    return (
      <>
        <div className="UserList">
          <h1>Users</h1>
          <ul>{usersList}</ul>
        </div>
        <Details user={this.state.selectedUser} />
      </>
    );
  }


  componentDidMount() {
    fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => {
        this.setState({ usersData: data })
      })
      .catch(err => this.setState({ error: err.message }))
  }
}


render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

When i am doing console.log selecteduser.albums inside findalbum function it is showing the data but when i did it in the li line it shows cant read size of undefined
i need to create a react app which shows list of users and their name username and email corresponding to each user we have albums we need to show album number also but i cant do it

is there any problem with pass by value or pass by reference in JS?

Answer (score 0):

It's very wrong to update the state directly in react. Instead, use `setState` with a `map` and change anything related to a substate there. Also a tip, instead of passing the Id in the forEach and finding the user, just pass the user

Comment: i am unable to understand your point :(